# Ace Editor HighlightRules, rule nested endlessly

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, ace-editor

With Ace Editor **HighlightRules**, I am wondering how to define rule that can be nested infinitly.

```
const rules = {
  start: [
    { ...segmentationName, next: 'segmentation' },
  ],
  segment: [
    { ...enclosingOperatorStart, next: 'enclosingOperator' },
    segmentCommand,
    { ...emptyLine, next: 'segmentation' },
  ],
  enclosingOperator: [
    segmentCommand,
    { ...enclosingOperatorEnd, next: 'segment' },
  ],
};
```

In the rules above, I would like `enclosingOperator` to be nested endlessly in order to be able to do allow the below example.

```
@Frankenstein/tf1-et-vous/PhotosList  //segmentationName
host www.tf1.fr                       //segmentCommand
path /tf1-et-vous/*
and (                                 //enclosingOperatorStart
path */photos/*                       //segmentCommand
path */photos-* 
or (                                  //enclosingOperatorStart
path */photos/*
path */photos-*
path */photo/*
)                                     //enclosingOperatorEnd
path */photo/*
)                                     //enclosingOperatorEnd
```

I could add `enclosingOperatorStart` node in `enclosingOperator` step but then in `enclosingOperatorEnd`, the **next** need to be `segment` if top level of the stack otherwise `enclosingOperator`

```
const rules = {
  start: [
    { ...segmentationName, next: 'segmentation' },
  ],
  segment: [
    { ...enclosingOperatorStart, next: 'enclosingOperator' },
    segmentCommand,
    { ...emptyLine, next: 'segmentation' },
  ],
  enclosingOperator: [
    { ...enclosingOperatorStart, next: 'enclosingOperator' },
    segmentCommand,
    { ...enclosingOperatorEnd, next: '?????????' },
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `push: <statename>` to add state to the stack and `next: pop` to remove it. Note that to use this you need to call `this.normalizeRules()` in the constructor.